# Class Declaration:Linker Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am trying to make a BST class in separate files but I am getting the linker command failure. I have checked many times but I am not able to find the error. Here is the code.

BST.h

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

class BST
{
    private:
    node *root;

    public:
    BST();
    void Insert(int);
    bool Search(int);
    bool Delete(int);
    void Display();
};

#endif
```

BST.cpp

```
#include "BST.h"

BST::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
}

void InsertNode(node *&, int);
void BST::Insert(int val)
{
    InsertNode(root, val);
}

bool SearchNode(node *&, int);
bool BST::Search(int val)
{
    return SearchNode(root, val);
}
bool DeleteNode(node *&, int);
bool BST::Delete(int val)
{
    return DeleteNode(root, val);
}

void InOrderTraversalDisplay(node *&);
void BST::Display()
{
    InOrderTraversalDisplay(root);
}

void InsertNode(node *&ptr, int val)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        ptr = new node;
        ptr->data = val;
        ptr->left = NULL;
        ptr->right = NULL;
    }

    else if (val > ptr->data)
    {
        InsertNode(ptr->right, val);
    }
    else if (val <= ptr->data)
    {
        InsertNode(ptr->left, val);
    }
}

void InOrderTraversalDisplay(node *&ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "tree is empty" << endl;
    }

    if (ptr->left != NULL)
    {
        InOrderTraversalDisplay(ptr->left);
    }

    cout << ptr->data << endl;

    if (ptr->right != NULL)
    {
        InOrderTraversalDisplay(ptr->right);
    }
}

bool SearchNode(node *&ptr, int val)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (ptr->data == val)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (val > ptr->data)
        {
            return SearchNode(ptr->right, val);
        }

        else if (val < ptr->data)
        {
            return SearchNode(ptr->left, val);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int Getsuccessor(node *ptr)
{
    ptr = ptr->right;
    while (ptr->left != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->left;
    }
    return ptr->data;
}

int Getsuccessor(node *);
bool DeleteNode(node *&ptr, int val)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    else if (val < ptr->data)
    {
        return DeleteNode(ptr->left, val);
    }

    else if (val > ptr->data)
    {
        return DeleteNode(ptr->right, val);
    }

    else
    {
        if (ptr->left == NULL && ptr->right == NULL)
        {
            delete ptr;
            ptr = NULL;
            return true;
        }

        else if (ptr->left != NULL && ptr->right == NULL)
        {
            node *temp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->left;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }

        else if (ptr->left == NULL && ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            node *temp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->right;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            int succ;
            succ = Getsuccessor(ptr);
            ptr->data = succ;
            return DeleteNode(ptr->right, succ);
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BST.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    BST b;
    b.Insert(5);
    b.Insert(4);
    b.Delete(4);
    b.Delete(14);
    b.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

It is giving the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BST::Delete(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-4bcc78.o
  "BST::Insert(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-4bcc78.o
  "BST::Display()", referenced from:
      _main in main-4bcc78.o
  "BST::BST()", referenced from:
      _main in main-4bcc78.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: A message like this typically means that you're trying to link main.cpp or main.o without telling the linker to also use BST.cpp or BST.o. What command line are you using to link your program?

Comment: Perhaps you're forgetting to include BST.cpp as part of the compilation?

Could you show us the command you're using to compile?

Comment: I am using Vscode 1.30.1 on MacBook

Comment: I am using vscode and I am running my code through code runner extension

Comment: Thanks. I Was missing bst.cpp in main. :/